# Why my code does not display the date?

Tags: php, html, css, date

I'm using CSS and HTML. I'm putting the PHP code inside the HTML, yet the result does not display. Can you help me around? Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="sidebar_1" class="sidebar one_quarter">
  <aside>
    <!-- #### -->
     <section>

     <div>
        <h2 class="title">Latest Announcement</h2>

        <div>The announcements will move here.
            <?php echo date("D , F.d.Y"); ?><br><span id=clock style="position:relative;"></span>

            <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <?php include('annohome.php'); ?>
            </table>
        </div>
     </div>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: What CSS are you using?

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: Did you save this with a PHP extension and upload it to a server (or use localhost)? PHP won't work inside raw HTML files...

Comment: echo date("D , F.d.Y"); is correct statement check what other have mentioned like file extension and css etc

Comment: what DOES it display?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: works for me http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/htc-rpe

Comment: yeah, it should be displaying Wed , February.12.2014.. but the template (css) that im using doesnt display anything. just empty spaces. so i guess the css styling wont let it display.

Comment: If you view source, does it display the date. The CSS won't affect PHP output...What happens if you just put `<?php echo date("D , F.d.Y"); ?>` in a blank `.php` file - does it display then?

Comment: i tried the code in empty php page, but only "Latest Announcement" and "The announcements will move here." appear.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have your timezone set. Some servers require that you set the timezone before you can actually use date.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

`echo date("D , F.d.Y");`
results in Wed , February.12.2014

Your server might also be hiding all php errors, so it might be necessary to php_ini set them on at the very beginning of the file.
`error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use either **`date_default_timezone_set()`** or a **`datetime`** object, and the user would have to set their own timezone in an options menu somewhere.
Otherwise, PHP is a server side language and has no idea what time it is on the user's end.

```
   // set the default timezone to use. Available since PHP 5.1
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');


    // Prints your date format 
     echo date("D , F.d.Y");
```